# Changing an array within an object (and vice versa) changes all references to that array before and after the change

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

In JavaScript, it appears if I define an array, print that array to the console, then change the array, then print to the console again, the two printings will appear different. Same for objects. This makes sense to me - the first time I print it, it hasn't changed yet, and the second time it has been changed.

However, through testing I've found that if I define an object *within* an array, print it, change the object, then print again, both printings will be the same (they will both be the changed version). Similarly if I define an array *within* an object, print it, change the array, then print it again, both printings will be the same (they will both be the changed version).

I think this may be related to passing by reference or by value? But I'm unclear how to relate that concept here. Some articles that I think may be related to my answer:

(SO) [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

(SO) [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

If anyone could help explain I would be very appreciative. Here are the tests I wrote to exemplify what discrepancy I'm asking about:

```
// Testing changing an array
// RESULT: Array console.logs are DIFFERENT before and after the change.
var arr123 = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr123);
arr123[0] = 4;
arr123[1] = 5;
arr123[2] = 6;
console.log(arr123);

// Testing changing an object
// RESULT: Object console.logs are DIFFERENT before and after the change.
var obj123 = {
    first: 1,
    second: 2,
    third: 3
};
console.log(obj123);
obj123.first = 4;
obj123.second = 5;
obj123.third = 6;
console.log(obj123);

// Testing changing an object inside of an array.
// RESULT: Array console.logs are THE SAME before and after the change, reflecting the change.
var arrOfAnObj = [
    {first: 1, second: 2, third: 3}
];
console.log(arrOfAnObj);
arrOfAnObj[0].first = 4;
arrOfAnObj[0].second = 5;
arrOfAnObj[0].third = 6;
console.log(arrOfAnObj);

// Testing changing an array inside of an object.
// RESULT: Object console.logs are THE SAME before and after the change, reflecting the change.
var objOfAnArr = {
    arr: [1, 2, 3]
};
console.log(objOfAnArr);
objOfAnArr.arr[0] = 4;
objOfAnArr.arr[1] = 5;
objOfAnArr.arr[2] = 6;
console.log(objOfAnArr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all your cases you are modifying the initial object, it's just related to how and when the browser reads the object you passed it through `console.log()`.

### Explanation

I executed your code in [this repl](https://repl.it/BxSZ) and the results are always different there.

I executed in chrome and I could reproduce you case. So it has to do with when the browser reads your variable. Because in the first two cases the variable has only one level so chrome shows you the values inline, and therefore reads the object at the point where it is logged.

In the last two cases you have one more level so chrome reads the object reference when you expand the object in the console.

Also I noticed that chrome displays your logs differently whether you run your code while the dev tools are open or when you run your code *before* opening the dev tools.

If you run the code before opening the dev tools you get the following output:

[image]

Whereas if you open the dev tools before running the code you get the following output:

[image]

Comment: WOW thank you I can't believe this was just a browser issue! Thank you for explaining so thoroughly, that makes a lot of sense. I'm glad my understanding of JavaScript references wasn't just completely wrong :)